# Ray - RLlib - Error with Custom env - continuous action space - DDPG - offline experience training?

Tags: offline, reinforcement-learning, ray, policy-gradient-descent

Error while using offline experiences for DDPG. custom environment dimensions (action space and state space) seem to be inconsistent with what is expected in DDPG RLLIB trainer.

Ubuntu, Ray 0.7 version (latest ray), DDPG example, offline dataset. 
Used sampler builder for offline dataset.

Estimated DQN with this experience data and it ran through. Changed environment action space to be continuous (Box(,1)) and DDPG did not work.

```py
from ray.tune.registry import register_env

TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE = 512
class mmt_ctns_offline_logs(gym.Env):
    def __init__(self):
        self.action_space = Box(0,50,shape=(,1), dtype=np.float32) #one dimension action space, values range 0 to 50 max
        self.observation_space = Box(-100000, 100000, shape=(,58), dtype=np.float32) #58 columns in state space

register_env("mmt_env_ctnaction", lambda config: mmt_ctns_offline_logs()) #register custom environment 

#define the configuration. Some of these are defaults. But I have explicitely defined them for clarify (within my team)
config_dict = {"env": "mmt_env_ctnaction", "evaluation_num_episodes":50, "num_workers": 11, "sample_batch_size": 512, 
               "train_batch_size": TRAIN_BATCH_SIZE, 
               "input": "<experience_replay_folder>/", 
               "output": "<any_folder>", "gamma": 0.99, 
               "horizon": None,  
               "optimizer_class": "SyncReplayOptimizer", 
               "optimizer": {"prioritized_replay":True},
               "actor_hiddens": [128, 64], "actor_hidden_activation": "relu",
               "critic_hiddens": [64, 64], "critic_hidden_activation": "relu", "n_step": 1,
               "target_network_update_freq": 500,
               "input_evaluation": [], 
               "ignore_worker_failures":True, 'log_level': "DEBUG",
    "buffer_size": 50000,
    "prioritized_replay": True,
    "prioritized_replay_alpha": 0.6,
    "prioritized_replay_beta": 0.4,
    "prioritized_replay_eps": 1e-6,
    "compress_observations": False,
    "lr": 1e-3,
    "actor_loss_coeff": 0.1,
    "critic_loss_coeff": 1.0,
    "use_huber": False,
    "huber_threshold": 1.0,
    "l2_reg": 1e-6,
    "grad_norm_clipping": True,
    "learning_starts": 1500,
    }

config = ddpg.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy() #dqn.DEFAULT_CONFIG.copy()
for k,v in config_dict.items():
    config[k] = v
config_ddpg = config
config_ddpg

run_experiments({
  'NM_testing_DDPG_offpolicy_noIS': {
    'run': 'DDPG',
    'env': 'mmt_env_ctnaction',
    'config': config_ddpg,
    'local_dir': "/oxygen/narasimham/ray/tmp/mmt/mmt_user_27_DDPG/" 
  },
})
```

Expected results from DDPG iterations.

Actual - ERROR:-

```
ray.exceptions.RayTaskError: ray_DDPGTrainer:train() (pid=89635, host=ip-10-114-53-179)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf_p36n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/rllib/utils/tf_run_builder.py", line 49, in get
    self.feed_dict, os.environ.get("TF_TIMELINE_DIR"))
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf_p36n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/rllib/utils/tf_run_builder.py", line 91, in run_timeline
    fetches = sess.run(ops, feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf_p36n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 877, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tf_p36n/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1076, in _run
    str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (512,) for Tensor 'default_policy/action:0', which has shape '(?, 1)'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with action space definition as follows:

```
self.action_space = Box(0,50,shape=(1,), dtype=np.float32)
```